# Google GIN AbstractGinModule & GWT.Create()

Tags: gwt, dependency-injection, guice

I have a class that extends AbstractGinModule

**like:**

```
 public class ClientModule extends AbstractGinModule {

  public ClientModule() { }

 @Override   
  protected void configure() {
  ...
  ...   
  bind(...class).annotatedWith(...).to(...class).in(Singleton.class);
  ...
  }
 }
```

The idea that I have is to bind one class with another class based on a value stored in a property file.

**like:**

param contains the value coming from the property file

```
if(param.equals("instanceB"))
   bind(a.class).to(b.class)
else
   bind(a.class).to(c.class)
```

I have a class that access this property file and return a string with the value.
This class is called: InstanceParameters.java

I would like to get an instance of this class within my ClientModule.
But I don't find any way to do it.
I tried with:

```
- InstanceParameters param = new InstanceParameters ();
- GWT.create(InstanceParameters.class); (Error because this method should only be used on the client side)
```

Is there a way to access this InstanceParameters class within this clientModule?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You haven't posted the `InstanceParameters` class, but I'm guessing that you are using some Java classes in it to read files from the HDD - something which is not supported by GWT's subset of JRE. What exactly are you trying to achieve by "controlling" the compilation via a property file? Why can't you do that from the Java classes (for example, via annotations)?

Comment: The instanceParameters class is using a Dictionary object "com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Dictionary". In the constructor of InstanceParameters I instanciate the dictionary by "this.parameters = Dictionary.getDictionary("NameOfFile");" . And this is the method that I'm using to get the value from this file "return parameters.get("applicationTitleShort");". Normally it should be ok.

Comment: I just tried to create a simple class with one attribute. (associated getter & setter). And I can instantiate  this one in the ClientModule.
I don't get it...

Comment: I'm just trying to change to visual component according to a property.
This property is nothing accept a simple value that allow me to understand in which mode the application is launch.
Like rich mode & simple mode(Less component on the client side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to read the file before launching the application - just before creating the `AbstractGinModule` (via `GWT.create`). So, load the `Dictionary` in your `onModuleLoad` method and pass the parameters, either as a whole `InstanceParameters` class or as the extracted String, via a provider or any other means.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was not sure that I correclty understood you answer but I did the following: in the onloadModule() I receive the dictionary, I take the value coming from .property file. I do the test in this loadmodule. Depending on the value, I use one module or another one. Do you think it's correct?

Comment: Yep, that's correct - I was suggesting putting the "testing" part into the module itself, but yours works better when, for example, the configuration (that is, the module extending `AbstractGinModule`) gets more complicated, etc. (on the other hand, you have to keep two Gin modules updated...) I can't seem to recall atm, but I'm quite sure there was a way to pass values to Gin (in worst case, use `public final static` fields in your GWT module, ugh).

Comment: Perfect. In the meantime. I will leave it like this.
I will investigate to pass the value to GIN late. Thanks a lot ;-)